# Unable to fetch newly created video files through getContentResolver().query() on all OS versions

Tags: android, provider

I am trying to fetch all the video files present in the device using the code below:

```
public void fetchVideoURIs() {
    ArrayList<String> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    try {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do {
            videoList.add((cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA))));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code is working fine when app runs for the first time, but after that when I record a new video and call the same code the same number of video Uri's are fetched in the array list

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I looked into the post but my problem is in every version of android and i am able to fetch the video uri's for the first time but after that every time i call the function the same no. of video uri's are returned even when i have new videos

Comment: at that time is your video is save in ur memory?

Comment: @duggu, yes i can see it in gallery as well as mx player

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem in past. If you know `filename`, you can use scan file intent to make it to be listed in gallery:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(filename);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
Activity.this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```